# Get the Version of an MSI Package Installer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer

I need to get the Version of an MSI Package, so I can check if I need to update the software or everything is up to date.

I tried the following solution and also added msi.dll from system32 as reference:

```
Public Function GetRevisionFromMSI(ByVal sMSIFilePath As String, ByVal sEXEFileName As String) As String
        Dim oInstaller As WindowsInstaller.Installer
        Dim oDb As WindowsInstaller.Database
        Dim oView As WindowsInstaller.View = Nothing
        Dim oRecord As WindowsInstaller.Record
        Dim sSQL As String
        Dim sRevision As String = "Not Found"
        Try
            oInstaller = CType(CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer"),
                           WindowsInstaller.Installer)
            oDb = oInstaller.OpenDatabase(sMSIFilePath, 0)
            sSQL = "SELECT `Component`.`ComponentId`,`File`.`FileName`, `File`.`Version`,`Component`.`Condition` FROM `Component`,`File` WHERE `Component`.`Component` = `File`.`Component_`"
            oView = oDb.OpenView(sSQL)
            oView.Execute()
            Do
                oRecord = oView.Fetch
                If oRecord Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                If oRecord.StringData(2).ToUpper.Contains(sEXEFileName.ToUpper) And (oRecord.StringData(2).ToUpper.Contains("CONFIG") = False) Then
                    'oTrace.WriteTraceLog("GetRevisionFromMSI", "Version Located " & oRecord.StringData(3), False, 1)
                    sRevision = oRecord.StringData(3)
                End If
            Loop
            Return sRevision
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return sRevision
        Finally
            oRecord = Nothing
            If Not (oView Is Nothing) Then
                oView.Close()
            End If
            oView = Nothing
            oDb = Nothing
            oInstaller = Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

But I get an MSI API Exception on this line:
`oDb = oInstaller.OpenDatabase(sMSIFilePath, 0)`

Also I really need the Version for other things too, so a workaround doesnt work for me.

Hope you can help me out with this one :)